# How to test if packet has been tagged with classid

Tags: linux, iptables, traffic-shaping, tc, cgroup

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue I'm having related to IFB Mirroring which I'm attempting to deploy based on this question: [Tc: ingress policing and ifb mirroring](https://serverfault.com/questions/350023/tc-ingress-policing-and-ifb-mirroring)

My theory is that since the ingress traffic is being redirected to/via ifb to be controlled by egress rules, I should be able to limit the ingress bandwidth via a combination tc and of Linux Control Groups net_cls controller, which can tag packets with a classid.

However its not working.  I'm theorizing that since the packets start off from ingress, they aren't being tagged even though they end up being treated as egress.  However, the only way I can think to test this is by actually looking at the packet and seeing if the class is there.

Not sure how to do this.  I'm thinking possibly tcpdump can but don't know the relevant flags.

If anyone has any ideas about my larger problem I'd appreciate those as well!

Cheers!