# Linux: limit specific port rate by combining tc with iptables does not work as expected

Tags: linux, iptables, tc

The script blow tries to limit the incoming rate of the port 2000, when using iptables
to mark the `INPUT` packets does not work, but `OUTPUT` works fine.

I use `nc -kl 2000` on machine `10.0.1.54` and `iperf -c 10.0.1.54 -p 2000 -t 10` on another machine to test it.

Why `OUTPUT` works but not `INPUT`?

```
dev=enp3s0
ip_addr=10.0.1.54
ip_port=2000

rate_limit=20kbit
htb_class=10

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" = "enable" ]; then
    echo "enabling rate limits"
    tc qdisc del dev $dev root > /dev/null 2>&1
    tc qdisc add dev $dev root handle 1: htb

    tc class add dev $dev parent 1: classid 1:$htb_class htb rate $rate_limit ceil $rate_limit
    tc filter add dev $dev parent 1: prio 0 protocol ip handle $htb_class fw flowid 1:$htb_class

    # marking the INPUT chain does dot work as expected
    #iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -d $ip_addr -p tcp --dport $ip_port -j MARK --set-mark $htb_class

    # marking the OUTPUT chain works fine
    iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s $ip_addr -p tcp --sport $ip_port -j MARK --set-mark $htb_class
elif [ "$1" = "disable" ]; then
    echo "disabling rate limits"
    tc qdisc del dev $dev root > /dev/null 2>&1

    #iptables -t mangle -D INPUT -d $ip_addr -p tcp --dport $ip_port -j MARK --set-mark $htb_class
    iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -s $ip_addr -p tcp --sport $ip_port -j MARK --set-mark $htb_class
elif [ "$1" = "show" ]; then
    tc qdisc show dev $dev
    tc class show dev $dev
    tc filter show dev $dev
    iptables -t mangle -vnL INPUT
    iptables -t mangle -vnL OUTPUT
else
    echo "invalid arg $1"
fi
```

Comment: Why is the `INPUT` mangle action commented out?  What specifically "doesn't work as expected"?

Comment: Using the `INPUT` or `PREROUTING` chain can't limit the rate, but I have doubts why they can't do this.
The `OUTPUT` chain works well, this is why I comment out the `INPUT` chain.

Comment: Maybe I find the answer,
[There are two modes of traffic shaping, INGRESS and EGRESS. INGRESS handles
incoming traffic and EGRESS outgoing traffic. Linux does not support
shaping/queuing on INGRESS, but only policing. Therefore IFB exists, which we
can attach to the INGRESS queue while we can add any normal queuing like
FQ_CODEL as EGRESS queue on the IFB device.](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) Right?

Comment: That looks like a reasonable explanation.  I'm more familiar with Cisco IOS' implementation of qos, which has similar restrictions on shaping.  If this gentoo link answers your question, consider adding an answer with that information.

Answer (score 2):

I try to answer this question by listing links below:

> There are two modes of traffic shaping, INGRESS and EGRESS. INGRESS handles incoming traffic and EGRESS outgoing traffic. Linux does not support shaping/queuing on INGRESS, but only policing. Therefore IFB exists, which we can attach to the INGRESS queue while we can add any normal queuing like FQ_CODEL as EGRESS queue on the IFB device. [http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping]

- [Why tc cannot do ingress shaping? Does ingress shaping make
  sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881921/why-tc-cannot-do-ingress-shaping-does-ingress-shaping-make-sense)
- [Tc: ingress policing and ifb mirroring](https://serverfault.com/questions/350023/tc-ingress-policing-and-ifb-mirroring)

So, my solution to this question is:

```
#!/bin/bash

dev=enp3s0
ifb_dev=ifb0
ip_addr=10.0.1.54
ip_port=2000

rate_limit=20kbit
htb_class=10

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

modprobe ifb
ifconfig ifb0 up

if [ "$1" = "enable" ]; then
    echo "enabling rate limits"

    tc qdisc add dev $dev handle ffff: ingress
    tc filter add dev $dev parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev $ifb_dev

    tc qdisc add dev $ifb_dev root handle 1: htb
    tc class add dev $ifb_dev parent 1: classid 1:$htb_class htb rate $rate_limit ceil $rate_limit

    tc filter add dev $ifb_dev parent 1: protocol ip prio 1000 u32 match ip dport 2001 0xffff flowid 1:$htb_class

elif [ "$1" = "disable" ]; then
    echo "disabling rate limits"

    tc qdisc del dev $dev root > /dev/null 2>&1
    tc qdisc del dev $dev ingress > /dev/null 2>&1
    tc qdisc del dev $ifb_dev root > /dev/null 2>&1
    tc qdisc del dev $ifb_dev ingress > /dev/null 2>&1

elif [ "$1" = "show" ]; then

    tc qdisc show dev $dev
    tc class show dev $dev
    tc filter show dev $dev

else
    echo "invalid arg $1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

what jinzheng said is right, you cannot shape ingress traffic.
but you can do it like captain jack sparrow...change the facts.

create a openvpn connection between your host and a vps with "redirect-gateway" so all the traffic goes over the vps.
so that it looks like this:
your home network/pc -> internet -> vps -> internet

what for your home network is INGRESS is EGRESS for the vps
then shape the outgoing interface on the vps.

some tips:
remember to specify your home network/ip or you will kill the vps upload rate.
the vps has to have better bandwidth than your homenetwork, measure the bandwith. in germany you could just get a 7€ vps from hetzner.de they are pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary do to that, its simple you just need to patch kernel and iptables and than you can shape incoming traffic, + if youre using LXC then you don't even need to patch anything, just on KVM