# Shape Traffic on specific ports on linux using IPTables

Tags: iptables

How can I shape (limit) traffic of ports: 22, 10011, 30033 for teamspeak3, to 1mbit/s? Primary using IPTables, because I only use them

Comment: It's called Quality of Service, and a search on QoS linux will provide a number of howto's. Can you try one of those?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yea I installed it, but its complicated a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this question sounds simple enough, it's not, this gets complex very quickly, incoming rate control is confusing, however, someone already gave a good answer here:

https://serverfault.com/a/666134/422034