# Create IFB with name or ID in Ubuntu server

Tags: tc, bandwidth-control, ubuntu-16.04, modprobe

I am doing some work relate to  limit income bandwidth (ingress) of a NIC in Ubuntu 16.04. Seem like we cannot limit the income bandwidth directly but have to use IFB. In this
[this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/350023/tc-ingress-policing-and-ifb-mirroring) we have a good tutorial using IFB to finish the job. I followed it an successed.

But I wonder if there is someway to create IFB with a name or id. Instead of:

```
modprobe ifb numifbs=n
```

Can I create an IFB with name such as

```
create ifb name="ifb_1"
```

Lately, sometime I would need to delete it and an ID is necessary.
I need to do some programmatical job with it and `modprobe ifb numifbs=n` not seem to be convenient for my coding job.